# PHP - close prepared stmt

Tags: php, mysqli

I am referring [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php)

I have something like

```
  function getData(){
     $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE emailID=?";
     $stmt = mysqli_prepare($query);
     if(false == $stmt){
         //handleerror Call
     }
     $bindParam = mysqli_stmt_bindParam($stmt,"s","a@a.com");
     if(false == $bindParam){
       **Do I need to close stmt here?**
       //handleError
     }
     $execute = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
     if(false == $execute){
       **Do I need to close stmt here?**
       //handle error
     }
    **Or Stmt will automatically get closed at the end of a function?**
  }
```

Any suggestions how to close stmt?

My doubt is that where should I call? Or will PHP automatically closes each statement at the end of a function? Because scope ends there.

I know how to Call. But I want to know should I call in this scenario or automatically will php closes when function ends.

Comment: `mysqli_close_stmt($stmt)` What didn't you understand on the php manual page?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois My doubt is that where should I call? Or will PHP automatically closes each statement at the end of a function? Because scope ends there.

Comment: I don't think you need to manually close a statement as long as you don't fetch a lot of data and need the  memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt->close();
```

It will close the statement.

Comment: He is not even using objects!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't close it yourself, PHP will do it at the end of the script/function. But you "should" close it whenever you don't need it anymore. Say for example, when an error occurs, you probably won't need it.

```
function getData(){
 $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE emailID=?";
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($query);
 if(false == $stmt){
     //handleerror Call
 }
 $bindParam = mysqli_stmt_bindParam($stmt,"s","a@a.com");
 if(false == $bindParam){
   //handleError
   mysqli_close_stmt($stmt)
   print "Binding failed";
 }
 $execute = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 if(false == $execute){
   mysqli_close_stmt($stmt)
   //handle error
 }
//if you haven't closed, PHP will close it now
}
```